# Deploy local angularjs application to webserver

Tags: angularjs

Hi all i have completed my webapplication using angularjs, In local iam using tomact server in eclipse and it is working fine, Now i want to deploy my application to webserver what is the process to do it.

```
For ex : my local url is : http://localhost:8080/Hms/#/
i want to the url as http://www.hms.com
```

Please help me i am new in angularjs

Comment: you would need to first build it.. move all html/js and into a build folder and then host it in IIS or whatever you want to use. its a very vauge question to answer actually...

Comment: Do you own the domain `hms.com`? Do you know what a web host is?

Comment: That completely depends on where and what you'll be deploying it to.  Here is a good place to start.  https://masteringmean.com/lessons/345-Packaging-and-Deploying-AngularJS-Web-Applications

Comment: @entre I want to know what is the process to deploy..

Comment: @Ageonix  I want to know what is the process to deploy step by step

Answer (score 1):

If your angular web application depends on Tomcat server;

1. If you haven't own server for web hosting which has http ://www.hms.com, your hosting provider should provide Tomcat feature.
2. If you have own server for web hosting which has http ://www.hms.com, just copy paste your all files in your project folder e.g. $TOMCAT_PATH/webapps/your-project-root/. And redirect http ://www.hms.com to Tomcat port (default is 8080)

If you are using only AngularJs, it shouldn't depend on Tomcat. You can use angular boilerplate https://github.com/adilkaraoz/ngbp. Github link provides information in details. With ngbp, just copy build folder inside into the your web hosting and at the and you have http //www.hms.com url which include your web files.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy this project same as how you are deploying other web applications in tomcat. Hope you build a war file and deploy them.

Angularjs is a javascript framework as Jquery. For server it's javascript, which will be served back to the client as other js files.

Please refer how deployments are done tomcat. Just fyr, https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Thanks.

Comment: i want to know how to deploy my application frm localhost to webserver

Comment: Either you have to copy the war files from local host to your server or you need to CI in place.

Comment: do you have any links for that

Comment: Go to your project Directory and inside Dist Folder you will get war file that you copy on your tomcat.   Copy this file and goto your server stop tomcat and paste in webApp folder. Restart tomcat.

Comment: i know this if i do like this and restart server i will get url as http //localhost:8080/hms. i want to run my application in url for example http //www.hms.com.